# How can I fix this Access 2003 bug? Data Entry Auto-Generating a Value

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, data-entry

I'm experiencing an odd data entry bug in MS Access and I am hoping that someone can possibly help shed a bit of light on why this might be happening and how to fix it.

I have a data table that is defined in our SQL Server database.  The definition is below, with only the field names changed.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TextField1] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TextField2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Integer1] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_Integer1]  DEFAULT (0),
    [Integer2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LargerTextField] [nvarchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see from the definition of this table that there is nothing special about it.  The problem that I am having is with a linked data table in an MS Access 2003 database that links through ODBC to this table.

After defining and creating the data table in SQL Server, I opened my working Access Database and linked to the new table.  I need to manually create the records that belong in this table.  However, when I started to add the data rows, I noticed that as I tabbed out of the `LargerTextField` to a new row, the `LargerTextField` was being defaulted to '`2`', even though I had not entered anything nor defined a default value on the field?!

Initially, I need this field to be `Null`.  I'll come back later and with an update routine populate the data.  But why would MS Access default a value in my field, even though the schema for the table clearly does not define one?  Has anyone seen this or have any clue why this may happen?

**EDIT**

One quick correction, as soon as I tab into the `LargerTextField`, the value defaults to '`2`', not when I tab out.  Small, subtle difference, but possibly important.

As a test, I also created a new, fresh MS Database an linked the table.  I'm having the exact same problem.  I assume this could be a problem with either MS SQL Server or, possibly, ODBC.

Comment: Is it always 2? Does the 2 come from somewhere else?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error in Access 2010 and SQL Express 2005/SP4. Hopefully someone will be along with the right version of access.

Comment: @webturner-- The odd thing is, I have a ton of tables that I often maintain through ODBC and access.  Some of them have very similar schemas but I've never seen this type of behavior.  I can only call this type of behavior "bizarre".  I can't think of any context where this behavior would make sense, unless I had a default on the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, problem solved.  This isn't a bug but it was certainly not behavior I desire or expected.

This behavior is occurring because of the data I am manually entering in fields `Integer1` and `Integer2`.  I am manually entering a `0` as the value of `Integer1` and a `1` into `Integer2`.  I've never seen Access automatically assume my data inputs, but it looks like it's recognizing data that is sequentially entered.

As a test, I entered a record with `Integer1` set to `1` and `Integer2` set to `2`.  Sure enough, when I tabbed into `LargerTextField`, the value of `3` was auto-populated.

I hate that this was a problem because of user ignorance but, I'll be honest, in my past 10+ years of using MS Access I can not recall even once seeing this behavior. I would almost prefer to delete this question to save face but since it caught me off guard and I'm an experienced user, I might as well leave it in the StackExchange archives for others who may have the same experience. :/

Comment: I believe there is similar functionality in Microsoft Excel workbooks.  Could be helpful for data entry provided you know it's there but not much use otherwise.

Comment: I think that was also part of the confusion for me.  I also use Excel a lot and this behavior from within a spreadsheet is quite helpful.  I've seen this happen, and have used it, in Excel but I've never seen it from within Access.  In fact, I don't believe I would have noticed the solution if I hadn't considered that Excel behaves this way as well.

Comment: Wow, I certainly wouldn't have expected that either. There has to be a setting somewhere to control that. Sometimes this stuff can be 'too helpful'

Answer (score 1):

As an experiment fire up a brand-new Access DB and connect to this table to see if you get the same behavior. I suspect this Access DB was connected to a table like this in the past and had that default set. Access has trouble forgetting sometimes :)

Comment: I highly doubt this is the case but, to be sure, I'll give it a try.  I manage both the SQL Server database and this is a "helper" access db that I use for data querying and updating.  I've never created a table with such a name, much less linked one.  Thanks for the quick response, though.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I just created a new db, and link the table.  Same behavior.  Could this be an odd  bug with ODBC or SQL Server?